# Symfony2 - theme for multiple forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, themes, twig

Is there way to use diffrent themes for two (or more) forms on the same page.
I've 2 forms and I'd like to use theme "X" for first form and theme "Y" for second form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your theme before displaying your form.

You should try :

```
{% form_theme form 'ThemeX.html.twig' %}
    {{ form(formX) }}

{% form_theme form 'ThemeY.html.twig' %}
    {{ form(formY) }}
```

If that doesn't work (ie. second form theme declaration doesn't overwrite the first one), just use a separate template for your second form and insert it in your parent template using an include.

Try [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#child-forms](this page) of symfony doc for more information